# Making the Navigation controller in Detail view of Split View controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

How can we programmatically create a Navigation controller in Detailed view of Split view based iPAd App?

I tried the steps, provided in this [link](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/24/fixing-the-uisplitviewcontroller-template/), but could not replace the Detail view controller with Navigation controller in XIB.

Comment: There is useful link in stack overflow that can help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627550/using-multiple-detail-views-with-split-view-controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but i hate questions that aren't answered.

```
UIViewController * masterController = ... allocation/init ...
UIViewController * detailController = ... allocation/init ...
UINavigationController *detailNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailController ] autorelease];


UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController .viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterController , detailNavController, nil];
```